# Perl: regx pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl

Whenever i find the word ".abc.corp:" in a line on file, i would like to exclude those lines:

Example Line:

```
kubernte-fileserver-NN.abc.corp:/srv/export/storage/nsp_updates   1231231  123112  123123  89%  /devops
```

can someone help me to find out the correct regex pattern:

im trying out with below pattern match: unable to figure it out

```
/^(.*(?!\.abc\.corp).*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\%\s+([\/\w\d\.-]+)$/
```

I'm confused with subpattern group $1 with negative look around!

Comment: Why are you trying to cram everything into a single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "exclude it", I assume you want to exclude the entire line.

Your try will not exclude anything, because here Perl can always find some point in the share path to split it, where the split point is not immediately followed by `.abc.corp`, like if it splits it:

```
kubernte-fileserver-N
N.abc.corp:/srv/export/storage/nsp_updates
```

or (as it's actually going to do) just consume everything by the first `.*`, with nothing left for the second one.

I'd instead first try to match the string you're trying to avoid, and failing to do so, proceed with the actual handling:

```
if (/^\S+\.abc\.corp:/) {
    # SKIP
}
elsif (/^(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\%\s+([\/\w\d\.-]+)$/) {
    ...
}
```

Besides actually working, this makes the code *much* more readable.